# Convert MapPartitionsRDD to DataFrame and grouping data by 2 keys

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have a dataframe which looks like this:

```
  country | user | count
  ----------------------
  Germany | Sarah| 2
  China   | Paul | 1
  Germany | Alan | 3
  Germany | Paul | 1
          ...
```

What I am trying to do is to convert this dataframe to another which looks like this:

```
  dimension | value
  --------------------------------------------
  Country   | [Germany -> 4, China -> 1]
  --------------------------------------------
  User      | [Sarah -> 2, Paul -> 2, Alan -> 3]
          ...
```

At first I tried to do it by this:

```
  var newDF = Seq.empty[(String, Map[String,Long])].toDF("dimension", "value")
  df.collect()
    .foreach(row => { Array(0,1)
            .map(pos => 
             newDF = newDF.union(Seq((df.columns.toSeq(pos).toString, Map(row.mkString(",").split(",")(pos) -> row.mkString(",").split(",")(2).toLong))).toDF())
             )
     })
  val newDF2 = newDF.groupBy("dimension").agg(collect_list("value")).as[(String, Seq[Map[String, Long]])].map {case (id, list) => (id, list.reduce(_ |+| _))}.toDF("dimension", "value")
```

But the `collect()` was killing my driver. Therefore, I have tried to do it like this:

```
 class DimItem[T](val dimension: String, val value: String, val metric: T) 


 val items: RDD[DimItem[Long]] = df.rdd.flatMap(row => {
                                dims.zipWithIndex.map{case (dim, i) => 
                                                  new DimItem(dim, row(i).toString, row(13).asInstanceOf[Long])
                                                  }
                                })  
 // with the format [ DimItem(Country, Germany, 2), DimItem(User, Sarah, 2)], ...

val itemsGrouped: RDD[((String, String), Iterable[DimItem[Long]])] = items.groupBy(x => (x.dimension, x.value))
val aggregatedItems: RDD[DimItem[Long]] = itemsGrouped.map{case (key, items) => new DimItem(key._1, key._2, items.reduce((a,b) => a.metric + b.metric)}
```

The idea is to save in an RDD objects like (Country, China, 1), (Country, Germany, 3), (Country, Germany, 1), ... and then group it by the 2 first keys (Country, China), (Country, Germany), ... Once grouped, sum the count they have. Ex: having (Country, Germany, 3), (Country, Germany, 1) will become (Country, Germany, 4).

But once I get here, it tells me that in `items.reduce()` there is a mismatch: it expects a DimItem[Long] but gets a Long.

Next step will be to group it by the key "dimension" and create the `Map[String, Int]()`format in the column "value" and convert it to a DF.

I have 2 questions.

**First**: is this last code correct?

**Second**: How can I convert this MapPartitionsRDD into a DF?

Comment: what about removing entirely the RDDs and working only with dataframe API which has at least two big advantages comparing to RDDs?

Comment: Hi Alexandros, I tried to do everything with DataFrame API but somehow it didn't save the data as the list-map structure I expected. Could you provide some example code? I'll try to do it again as you pointed out, thanks for the advice!

Comment: Hi @rach23 I added the suggested approach based on dataframe API. Please let me know if it worked

Comment: Thanks Alexandros! It works. In case we had N columns instead of these 2 (Country and User), would you create one dataframe per column as in your example? Just to know your opinion about the most optimal approach given several columns.

Comment: well then just call `transform` function below for each column and eventually call union to append them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one solution based on dataframe API:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{lit, map_from_arrays, collect_list}

def transform(df :DataFrame, colName: String) : DataFrame = 
  df.groupBy(colName)
    .agg{sum("count").as("sum")}
    .agg{
      map_from_arrays(
        collect_list(colName),
        collect_list("sum")
      ).as("value")
    }.select(lit(colName).as("dimension"), $"value")

val countryDf = transform(df, "country")
val userDf = transform(df, "user")

countryDf.unionByName(userDf).show(false)

// +---------+----------------------------------+
// |dimension|value                             |
// +---------+----------------------------------+
// |Country  |[Germany -> 6, China -> 1]        |
// |User     |[Sarah -> 2, Alan -> 3, Paul -> 2]|
// +---------+----------------------------------+
```

**Analysis:** first we get the sum by country and user grouping by country and user respectively. Next we add one more custom aggregation to the pipeline which collects the previous results into a map. Map will be populated via [map_from_arrays](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#map_from_arrays) function found in Spark 2.4.0. The keys/values of the map we collect them with collect_list. Finally we union the two dataframes to populate the final results.